# Where is my downloaded program(thermo.chemical) located?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

After installing thermo.chemical, I wanted to know how I can check,

first of all, which version is installed on my computer and second where the program is located (path).
What do I have to enter in my terminal.

I tried the following, but it does not work.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

def clicked(arg):
    print(thermo.__version__())
    
button_download = widgets.Button(description = 'Version', button_style = 'primary') 
button_download.on_click(clicked)
display(button_download)
```

This error ist showed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-8d76d70a85bb> in clicked(arg)
      3 
      4 def clicked(arg):
----> 5     print(thermo.__version__)
      6 
      7 button_download = widgets.Button(description = 'Version', button_style = 'primary')

NameError: name 'thermo' is not defined
```

Comment: `"does not work."` is the most useless information. Do you get error message or what? Don't expect that we will run code to see error. And we can't see your screen, and we can't read in your mind - you have to put all details in question.

Comment: very often you can get version like `thermo.__version__`. And you can check localization with `thermo.__file__`

Comment: version you can also get with `pip freeze` - it list all installed modules with version's number.

Comment: first: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe you forgot to `import thermo`

Comment: BTW: you don't need button to use `print()`

Comment: i imported with

`from thermo.chemical import Chemical`

Comment: if you want to use `thermo....` then you have to use `import thermo`. Using `from thermo.chemical import Chemical` you have access only to `Chemical` but not to `thermo`

Comment: it worked with `from thermo.chemical import Chemical
from IPython.display import display
import thermo
import ipywidgets as widgets

def clicked(arg):
    print(thermo.__version__)
    
button_download = widgets.Button(description = 'Version', button_style = 'primary') 
button_download.on_click(clicked)
display(button_download)
`
first task is done! And it also worked with `thermo.__version__`, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Many modules have variable `__version__` and all modules, submodules and scripts have `__file__`

```
import thermo

print(thermo.__version__)
print(thermo.__file__)
```

---

**BTW:**

You have to `import thermo` to have access to elements in `thermo`.

Using `from thermo.chemical import Chemical` you have access only to `Chemical` but not to `thermo`.